# RxJava: How to retain Thread from upstream

Tags: java, android, rx-java

On Android some callbacks are always invoked on the main `Thread` by design, e.g. the following `ServiceConnection`:

```
private Completable dismissService() {
    return Completable.fromEmitter(new Action1<CompletableEmitter>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final CompletableEmitter completableEmitter) {
            final ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() {
                @Override
                public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                    // here always main Thread...
                    unbindService(this);
                    completableEmitter.onCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                    // no-op
                }
            };

            completableEmitter.setCancellation(new AsyncEmitter.Cancellable() {
                @Override
                public void cancel() throws Exception {
                    unbindService(conn);
                }
            });

            bindService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class), conn, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    });
}
```

However, I would like the Completable returned by `dismissService()` to emit its result on whatever `Thread` it was invoked on. I tried the following (hacky?) solution using a `newSingleThreadExecutor()`:

```
private Completable dismissServiceRetainingThread() {
    return Single.fromCallable(new Callable<Thread>() {
        @Override
        public Thread call() throws Exception {
            return Thread.currentThread();
        }
    }).flatMapCompletable(new Func1<Thread, Completable>() {
        @Override
        public Completable call(final Thread thread) {
            return Completable.fromEmitter(new Action1<CompletableEmitter>() {
                @Override
                public void call(final CompletableEmitter completableEmitter) {
                    final ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() {
                        @Override
                        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                            // here always main Thread...
                            unbindService(this);
                            completableEmitter.onCompleted();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                            // no-op
                        }
                    };

                    completableEmitter.setCancellation(new AsyncEmitter.Cancellable() {
                        @Override
                        public void cancel() throws Exception {
                            unbindService(conn);
                        }
                    });

                    bindService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class), conn, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                }
            }).observeOn(Schedulers.from(
                           Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(
                             new ThreadFactory() {
                               @Override
                               public Thread newThread(@NonNull Runnable runnable) {
                                 return thread;
                              }
                            }
              )));
        }
    });
}
```

However, that crashes with the following `IllegalThreadStateException`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.jenzz.rxjavathreadingtest, PID: 5307
              java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:930)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1348)
                  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:591)
                  at rx.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorSchedulerWorker.schedule(ExecutorScheduler.java:79)
                  at rx.Completable$28$1.onCompleted(Completable.java:1805)
                  at rx.internal.operators.CompletableFromEmitter$FromEmitter.onCompleted(CompletableFromEmitter.java:73)
                  at com.jenzz.rxjavathreadingtest.MainActivity$5$2$1.onServiceConnected(MainActivity.java:117)
```

Any ideas how I can jump back onto the original `Thread` that was previously used upstream e.g. using `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to return to the exact thread you were on. It might be busy when other threads in the same `Scheduler` are free, and unless it is the main thread, there is no guarantee that it even still exists when the callback returns.  It is available for more work or clean up as soon as your `call` method returns.  I think what you want is to execute on the same `Scheduler` as the original call.  AFIAK, there is no direct way to determine the current `Scheduler` for a thread either (there is a brittle way to determine some schedulers, mentioned at the bottom of this post).  So you can't easily do what you are trying to do. Defaulting to notifying on the main thread seems like sane behavior for this method.  If you want it to default to a different `Scheduler` you can tack on a `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())` or the scheduler of your choice.

As noted in the other answer, you could attempt to create a `Handler` if the current thread has a looper.  You would still be relying on the caller to make sure that thread is still viable when the callback occurs.  That seems like a higher level of responsibility than telling the caller the response will come on the main thread unless they select a different one using `observesOn`.

As a final thought, it might be possible to determine the correct scheduler for the standard ones returned by `Schedulers` by looking at the thread's name. They have predictable prefixes such as `RxNewThreadScheduler-1`, so a few `String.startsWith()` calls could isolate the correct schedular.  This is pretty brittle, though, because it will not correctly handle user created schedulers and the thread naming scheme could change in the future.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds reasonable. I have decided to just default to notifying on the main thread and document this behaviour in the JavaDoc. The caller can always tack on a `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())` like you suggested to switch right back to a background `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a `Handler` in  `dismissService()` and in your callback you could post back to the associated looper.

This only works if the thread calling into `dismissService()` is a looper thread.

EDIT: If you're specifically trying to do something on that io `Scheduler`. You might also be able to create a worker from the `Scheduler` and schedule your action that way.